# Get data from inside an iFrame on the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, html

I am trying to do something like this:

```
 var data = $('#upTar').contents();
 $("#fileRes").html(data);
```

Where #upTar is an iframe and #fileRes is a div, that is I want all the data from iframe (in HTML format) into the div.
The iframe is dynamically loaded.

**Edit**
The additional code looks like:

```
    $("#addMore").click(function() {  
         $("#progForm").submit();  
         $('#upTar').load(function() {  
         $("#title, #obj, #theory, #code, #output, #conc").val("");  
         var data = $('#upTar').contents().find("body").html();  
         alert(data);    
         $("#fileRes").html(data);  
        });  
     });
```

The target for form submit is an iframe (#upTar) on the same page. Once that one is loaded, I want its data to be transfered to div.

**CLOSURE EDIT**
Rather than trying to fetch the details from the iframe, I now call an ajax script to update the div.

Thanks All!

Comment: If the iframe is from a different domain then it is not possible.

Comment: Does `data` contain anything? Do you get any error message?

Comment: www vs no www?  (as in your page is www.foo.com and your iframe is foo.com?

Comment: currently I am testing over localhost on iis server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `$('#upTar').contents().find("body").html()`

`contents` itself return top-level HTMLElement node, you have to grab HTML from this node too. and you possibly don't want all the HTML including the head section, so first you need to find body tag.

Comment: I am using it as var data = $('#upTar').contents().find("body").html()  alert(data) is return empty alert.

Comment: is has to be a different domain, subdomain, port or protocol then.

Comment: ... or, your iframe does not contain body tag. or you call your script before the iframe is loaded.

Comment: I am doing it over localhost (IIS).

Comment: Yes, it seems, the script is being called before the iframe is loaded. I have altered my approach (read OP). Thanks!